# On GitHub, how can I get notified that someone who blocked me commented on my issue?

Tags: github, notifications, github-issues

On GitHub if User A blocks User B, User A is now free to comment on User B's issues without User B getting notified!

How can User B still get notified?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/search?q=author:UserB+commenter:UserA&type=Issues finds them.

So one could [use various time limits](https://github.com/search?q=author:UserB+commenter:UserA+updated:%3E2024-01-03T00:00:00%2B08:00&s=updated&type=Issues) in a daily *cron job* to find them.

Comment: Indeed, many User A's often ask User B questions in their comments on User
B's issues, then not understanding why User B doesn't give a timely
answer. This shows that the User A's are unaware of this  aspect of blocking on GitHub, which only exacerbates misunderstandings.